# Cakephp Login after Auth is set is not workng

Tags: cakephp

I have a mistake with Cakephp Login after Auth is set.

`$this->Auth->login()` it return 1 means true and also `$this->Auth->user()` and `$this->Session` return all valid data, that is stored in auth or session. I can get `something(id, username)` from session. but the problem is I can not logged in.  As the Auth is set so it is cakephp default feature to log me in to the app but it is not happening.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Simply follow the [tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html) step by step and you're done!

Comment: I dont even understand the issue? I assume you want to check if you're logged in? Well, read the book but there is $this->Auth->loggedIn(), and Auth->identify() and the callback Controller::isAuthorized().

Comment: I have already test it on another staging server, it works fine at there. But when i upload it to production server, it broke. As you say I have already checked it, after your comment I checked it again. But belive me it all fine. One thing to tell you I have no mod_rewite , I am using "Configure::write('App.baseUrl', env('SCRIPT_NAME'));" . is it the caused ?

Comment: @user1475072 make sure PHP sessions can even be written on your production machine.

Comment: Perhaps update the question to mention that your Auth setup works, but not on production. I suspect @jeremyharris 's hunch is correct too.